# Tinymce - getting the font color

Tags: tinymce

I have a page with tinymce. The text in the tinymce can be with two font colors: green and blue.

The first time the page loads, here's the content of the tinymce textarea:

```
"<p style="background-color: white; opacity: 1; color: green;">1&nbsp;line</p>
<p style="background-color: white; opacity: 1; color: blue;">1&nbsp;line345</p>
<p style="background-color: white; opacity: 1; color: blue;">1&nbsp;line</p>"
```

So, the first row is green, and the other lines are blue.

Right after that, I have a method for validation of the lines. All valid lines are colored blue, and the invalid lines are colored green, with this code:

```
.css("color", "blue")
```

In this case, all of the lines are valid and are quickly colored blue. I can see them and they are blue.

However, when I execute this line:

```
$('#myTinymceId').val()
```

I get the same paragraph as the previous one. The first line is still:

```
<p style="background-color: white; opacity: 1; color: green;">1&nbsp;line</p>
```

even though I can see it's blue. What can I do to get the correct color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another way to access the tinymce editor content. Try

```
tinymce.get('myTinymceId').getContent();
```